Designing Selection Algorithm with 3 parameters
I am designing a selection algorithm for a bit to search an item Bank to retrieve the best information for one student. I am going to measure baseline student proficiency before so the bit has the students profile. Instead of 2 parameters, subject mastery and learning preferences, I am going to have a 3rd parameter based on recording the student when they are taking the baseline assessments. Thus 3rd value will probably be something like facial gesture and subsequent emotional State. My question is , how should I approach designing the algorithm, the math too, where I know I will have to normalize all three, and other stuff..I am using Item Response Theory and Neural Network based Computer Adaptive Testing mechanisms to do this. Thanks in advance!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
